# How to post value to another page using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to post the value of dropdown selected value to another page. I will use this value to add in my query of auto complete. I've been stuck with this problem -_-.

```
id  |  cat_code | item_code| item    |   category  |
1   |  ACR-01   |  A00001  | pencil  | supplies    |
2   |  ACR-01   |  A00001  | ballpen | supplies    |
3   |  ACR-03   |  C00001  | Stapler |It equipment |
```

When I select supplies, the value of dropdown which is ACR-01 is what I need to post in autocomplete.php so I can add `$main = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["mainlist_id"]);` and this inside of where clause query `AND cat_code='$main'` so that only supplies item comes out in autocomplete function.

**Ajax.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tag").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
        selectFirst: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Drop1

```
<?php
$combo = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM category GROUP BY cat_code ORDER BY id");
$option = '';
while($row = $combo->fetch_assoc())
{
    $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['cat_code'].'">'.$row['category'].'</option>';
}
?>

<select id="main" name="main">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>
Auto Complete <input id="tag" type="text">
```

**Autocomplete.php**

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015") or die("Database Error");
    $auto = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["q"]);
    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM code WHERE item LIKE '%$auto%' GROUP BY id ORDER BY item" ); 

    if($sql)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            echo $row['item']."\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work. What I need is when I select the value should post to autocomplete to add in my query so I can get all right item depending on dropdown value.

```
$('#main').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'autocomplete.php',
        data: {mainlist_id : $(this).val()},
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#tag').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can send custom data via autocomplete in `source` option

Comment: are you getting any error through your ajax request? Check in firebug or in developer's toolbar

Comment: @Nouphal.M how to use that source option? Pardon me I'm a begginer in ajax :(

Comment: does the query string parameter use the same name?

Comment: @jogesh_pi I don't get any error. But my autocomplete doesn't work.

Comment: @JetLaggy yes it's the same, but when I add this $main = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["mainlist_id"]); and this inside of my where clause AND cat_code='$main' my autocomplete doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can specify custom source via `source` option. Send an ajax request in source option so that you can pass additional data via the request, in the following i am sending an additional key `customdata` which can be accessed by `$_GET['customdata']`:

```
$("#tag").autocomplete({
      source: function(request,response){
         $.ajax({
                  type: 'GET',
                  url: 'autocomplete.php?q='+request.term+'&customdata=Hello',
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function (data) {
                  response(data);
                  }
              });


    }
});
```

Comment: what should the value of $_GET['customdata']?

Comment: you can specify anyhing you like its just a GET variable, i have just given it for example the value of $_GET['customdata'] is Hello, you can specify any key value pair of your choice

Comment: You can get the selectbox option selected value `$( "#main option:selected" ).val();`

Comment: can you help me more? I'm having a hard time using ajax pardon me

Comment: What is your problem?